# Cron job with a dynamic date

Tags: cron, scheduling

I've been looking around but haven't found a solution to my particular problem.

I need to create a cron job to backup a file system on daily basis. But the application needs the current date/time to run.
Example:

`bundle exec thor migrator:export /var/tmp/backups --after "2016-12-22 00:00:00 -0700"`

How can I easily run the above command whereby the date will change daily? Time will remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following line is your example.

```
bundle exec thor migrator:export /var/tmp/backups --after "2016-12-22 00:00:00 -0700"
```

You could use a command substitution for this job.

```
bundle exec thor migrator:export /var/tmp/backups --after "$(date --iso) 00:00:00 -0700"
```

But I rather would recommend to put your command into a separate shell script and run the shell script from `cron`.

Comment: +1 for that last statement.  It's also a good idea to have a private `daily.sh` script that cron runs daily, and similarly for hourly and monthly jobs. The scripts could collect all tasks that you need to perform at those intervals, and it would keep the crontab very simple.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I see no immediate reason a regular user couldn't call  `run-parts ~/etc/cron.daily` or similar, which will conveniently run all scripts in a directory, a la `/etc/cron.daily`. No need to bunch different tasks into a single script.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `run-parts`? Of course, if you're on a Linux box.  I'm not.